# Un-rarring with java?

Tags: java, rar

In a piece of my code, I want to download a .rar (archive) file in a certain folder and unrar it, rather than download all the files one by one.

However, I couldn't find a way to do this.

Comment: Are you talking about server-side or client-side?

Comment: client-side, so the application downloads something for the user, and unrars it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either execute external unrar utility using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or use Java library like [JUnrar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar).

Answer (score 0):

Another library that handles RAR is 7-Zip-JBinding, it has a code snippet that you might want to take a look at:

http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/basic_snippets.html#extraction-single-file

the library it cross platform and supports many other compressed files other than RAR

the license is LGPLv2